# Passing a variable using .getJSON for conditional SQL Query

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

I have a page that generates a table and its content will be retrieved using `.getJSON`. But i have a variable to be passed for that conditional query. Here is my code,

```
<?php $cust_id = $_GET['cust_id']; ?>
<table class="display" id="invoice-disc-list" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>INVOICE #</th>
            <th>INVOICE DATE</th>
            <th>SALESMAN</th>
            <th>INVOICE AMOUNT</th>
            <th>DISCOUNT</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>

<script>
    $.getJSON('pages/lj_menu/monitoring/process/price_history_data.php', function(response) {
        var custid = '<?php echo $cust_id; ?>';
        // Initialize DataTables
        $('#invoice-disc-list').DataTable({
            iDisplayLength : 15,
            processing: true,
            data: response,
            columns: [
              {data: "INVOICE_NO"},
              {data: "INVOICE_DATE"},
              {data: "INVOICE_SALESMAN"},
              {data: "INVOICE_AMOUNT"},
              {data: "INVOICE_DISCOUNT"}
          ]
        });

        // Initialize AJAX onClick Data Send
        window.someGlobalOrWhatever = response.balance;
    });
</script>
```

how do i post `var custid = '<?php echo $cust_id; ?>';` to `price_history_data.php` that contains the query so that the data inside the table only shows data based on the `custid` variable that i send.. ?

Thanks again for the help

Comment: pass **custid** as a get parameter

Comment: what do you mean by that ? and how to do that ?

Comment: like this `$.getJSON("pages/lj_menu/monitoring/process/price_history_data.php?custid=<?php echo $cust_id; ?>", function(response)`

Comment: Using PHP first set some javascript variable to `cust_id`, then add that variable to url and in PHP get it as a url parameter, as Devendra suggested

Comment: @DevendraBhandari thank you, please post your answer so i can accept it as an correct answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass `custid` as a get parameter in the URL

```
<?php $cust_id = $_GET['cust_id']; ?>
<table class="display" id="invoice-disc-list" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>INVOICE #</th>
            <th>INVOICE DATE</th>
            <th>SALESMAN</th>
            <th>INVOICE AMOUNT</th>
            <th>DISCOUNT</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>

<script>
    $.getJSON('pages/lj_menu/monitoring/process/price_history_data.php?custid=<?php echo $cust_id; ?>', function(response) {
        var custid = '<?php echo $cust_id; ?>';
        // Initialize DataTables
        $('#invoice-disc-list').DataTable({
            iDisplayLength : 15,
            processing: true,
            data: response,
            columns: [
              {data: "INVOICE_NO"},
              {data: "INVOICE_DATE"},
              {data: "INVOICE_SALESMAN"},
              {data: "INVOICE_AMOUNT"},
              {data: "INVOICE_DISCOUNT"}
          ]
        });

        // Initialize AJAX onClick Data Send
        window.someGlobalOrWhatever = response.balance;
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you are:

```
$.getJSON('pages/lj_menu/monitoring/process/price_history_data.php', '<?php echo $cust_id; ?>')
    .done(function(response) {
        // Initialize DataTables
        $('#invoice-disc-list').DataTable({
            iDisplayLength : 15,
            processing: true,
            data: response,
            columns: [
              {data: "INVOICE_NO"},
              {data: "INVOICE_DATE"},
              {data: "INVOICE_SALESMAN"},
              {data: "INVOICE_AMOUNT"},
              {data: "INVOICE_DISCOUNT"}
          ]
        });

        // Initialize AJAX onClick Data Send
        window.someGlobalOrWhatever = response.balance;
    });
```